# Is it a good idea to always define a clustered index on a database table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I am currently looking at a performance problem with a widely used .NET CMS system, and have a particular table with approximately 5,000,000 records in it which is the root cause of these problems, just querying the contents of this table takes up to 2 minutes on my local development environment.

Looking at the schema for the table, I have noticed there is just a single unique nonclustered index and no clustered index.

The table & index are defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Language] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FieldId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NOT NULL
)


CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Unique] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [ItemId] ASC,
    [Language] ASC,
    [FieldId] ASC
)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions around indexes on this table to improve query performance and specifically, is it generally good practice to always define a clustered index on a table?

Thanks

Comment: In order to suggest which indexes would help, we'd need to know how you are accessing the table. What are the queries you execute against it?

Comment: For any "normal" data table - yes, I would always recommend a **good** clustered index (on a narrow, stable, unique and preferably ever-increasing column). This might not apply to temporary tables, tables used for e.g. bulk inserts and so on - but anything else does benefit from a good clustered index, yes

Answer (score 3):

i don't think you can say 'always' good or bad.

do you have an explain plan for the query that does not perform?

if the where clause of that query does not use the indexed columns, then an additional index may help dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agreeing with Randy in that it depends on what the table is primarily going to be used for. [This](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) is a great article on "the clustered index debate".

There's way too much to sum up here, but in general `INSERT` is always faster with a clustered index, `UPDATE` is *usually* faster, and `SELECT` depends more upon other factors like having covering non-clustered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Clustered index sorts the table on the index key and stores it physically in that order.
Which is why only 1 clustered index can be defined on any table. It is advisable to have ur clustered index on unique values for best results.

If there are a variety of queries which access your table(using columns which are not in the clustered index) it would be better to have more non clustered index on those columns filterd by these queries.

check [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for details on clustered index